# Loading a big gif with SDWebImage caused iOS app crash with memory error

Tags: ios, crash, gif, sdwebimage

I am fetching a full screen image from url returned from internet in my `UIImageView` on a `UIScrollView` with SDWebImage framework like this:

```
[imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"] options:SDWebImageCacheMemoryOnly completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
    if (!error) {
        //added as subview
    } else {
        //show error
    }
}];
```

When the image was with format of `jpg` or `png`, it shows well, even some normal sized `gif`. But when there was a big `gif`, it would cause crash and XCode gives such error:

```
Message from debugger: Terminated due to Memory Error
```

**UPDATE:** The `gif` image that causes crash everytime is `299px`*`299px` and `570KB` big. For those who are interested in seeing the gif, the link is:

```
http://ww4.sinaimg.cn/large/604e48d0jw1evcn03adjjg208b08bdv0.gif
```

I can recreate this every time I clicked on the preview thumbnail.
How can I solve this? What tool to use to observe the root cause? I did some research and I guess if it's caused by the fact that I was using the option: `SDWebImageCacheMemoryOnly`, and the big gif cost most of my app's memory so it crashed. Thanks.

Comment: Hi matt, I'll update my question regarding your question, thanks.

Comment: Hi matt, thanks, I will try to track it down, what's weird is except this `gif` image, other smaller ones or static images won't cause crash at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that I notice about your animated gif image is that it is a very long (in terms of *frame count*) animation - 3191 frames. Every single one of those frames is 300x300, for a total of almost 300 *million* pixels. And we *must* hold all those pixels in memory at once: there's no other way to display the frames at speed. And it seems to be coded as RGB, so every pixel is 4 bytes. If I'm right, that's more than a gigabyte of memory needed to display this thing. That certainly is what Graphic Converter is suggesting:

[image]

So you're right, I can well imagine that displaying this might be troublesome. My advice would be: don't.

Comment: Hey matt, I see...but I can see some apps do display such `gif` image perfectly. So I was wondering if I can degrade the `gif` or there should be other ways to do that.

Comment: Hi matt! So if I understand your advice is to don't use the GIF in an application?

Answer (score 3):

SDWebImage has its own implementation of GIF support. The problem is that they iterate thought all the frames and create bitmaps upfront:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    CGImageRef image = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, i, NULL);
    duration += [self sd_frameDurationAtIndex:i source:source];
    [images addObject:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:image scale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp]];
    CGImageRelease(image);
}
```

FLAnimatedImage on the other hand creates bitmaps on-demand and intelligently caches them.

Take a look at [FLAnimatedImage](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage). And image loaders that use it for GIF playback like [**Nuke**](https://github.com/kean/Nuke) (mine), [PINRemoteImage](https://github.com/pinterest/PINRemoteImage), FLAnimatedImage_AFNetworking etc. Or use FLAnimatedImage directly.